# UIDynamics - collision issue

Tags: ios7, collision-detection, uikit-dynamics, uidynamicbehavior, uicollisionbehavior

Here is little question about `UIDynamics`.

I have 8 square blocks laid out horizontally across the iPhone screen.
Each square is **40 x 40**. Since there are 8 of them, they fill up the width of the **320** screen.

I guess the picture is clear. Now comes the question:

When I apply a vertical gravity towards the bottom the blocks fall as I expect.
But when I apply a lateral gravity (left or right) they move by about one pixel or two each.
The last being therefore shifted by about 10 pixels or so.
Why is that?

I use:

```
collisionBehave.translatesReferenceBoundsIntoBoundary=YES;
```

in my code.

I would expect the blocks not to move at all when I apply a lateral gravity.
I think I do not quite understand how the collisions between the moving parts is handled.

Thanks in advance for any tip.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set your 8 squares into `UIDynamicItemsBehavior` and set the density of this behavior.